# How to read and writing ROS message efficient into files c++

Tags: ros, c++, binary, message, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

With the following code I am able to read and write ros message into binary files using c++.
But I have to create first memory buffer to use the ros ros::serialization::OStream or ros::serialization::IStream is there a way how to stream messages directly into files similar to a std::ofstream?

```
void LaserLineFilterNode::callback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& _msg) {

    {
        // Write to File
        std::ofstream ofs("/tmp/filename.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

        uint32_t serial_size = ros::serialization::serializationLength(*_msg);
        boost::shared_array<uint8_t> obuffer(new uint8_t[serial_size]);  // This i like to avoid

        ros::serialization::OStream ostream(obuffer.get(), serial_size); // This i like to avoid
        ros::serialization::serialize(ostream, *_msg); // I would like to use the ofstream here?
        ofs.write((char*) obuffer.get(), serial_size);  // This i like to avoid
        ofs.close();
    }
    {
        // Read from File to msg_scan_
        //sensor_msgs::LaserScan msg_scan_ --> is a class variable
        std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/filename.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
        ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
        std::streampos end = ifs.tellg();
        ifs.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
        std::streampos begin = ifs.tellg();

        uint32_t file_size = end-begin;
        boost::shared_array<uint8_t> ibuffer(new uint8_t[file_size]);  // This i like to avoid
        ifs.read((char*) ibuffer.get(), file_size);  // This i like to avoid
        ros::serialization::IStream istream(ibuffer.get(), file_size); // I would like to use the ifstream here?
        ros::serialization::deserialize(istream, msg_scan_);  // This i like to avoid
        ifs.close();
    }
    ....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128891/how-to-read-and-writing-ros-message-efficient-into-files-c++/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag has a C++ API for reading and writing bag files: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2